# How to position widgets absolutely in ScrollPanel?

Tags: java, gwt, scroll, panel, css-position

I want to make something like google maps widget. I need to position image tiles absolutely within ScrollPanel.

Is it possible directly or I should insert AbsolutePanel first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the images first in the AbsolutePanel.
Then add the AbsolutePanel in the ScollPanel.

Comment: This is impossible. I need to add new images while user scrolls panel and new regions appear.

Comment: OK. I guess you could check what part of the AbsolutePanel is visible inside the ScrollPanel, and trigger events, as you scroll. Of course if you scroll too fast all images will be loaded at once.  Another idea is not to use a ScrollPanel at all, have some navigation buttons, and create the URL for each click and display the image in a panel. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have failed to use ScrollPanel somehow.

Definetely I was to use AbsolutePanel, but I was also to put it into overflow:visible mode. Being in this mode, AbsolutePanel was not causing ScrollPanel behave correctly.

So, finally I made 2 AbsolutePanels, staying and moving ones. Moving one was inner and was containing tiles and was in overflow:fiexd mode. Staying one was outer and was located within SimpleLayoutPanel of my widget. My widget was located within RootLayoutPanel to catch resize events.